# Java: checking if a phone number fits a valid format

Tags: java

I am trying to find if a phone number fits the format (xxx)xxx-xxxx where x is a digit. First, I have the program for the length and the '(',')', and '-'. When I type in something that doesn't work, I get the logical output. However, when I type in a properly formatted number, my program doesn't return anything.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program04 {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String pN;

    System.out.print("Please enter a phone number (ddd)ddd-dddd :");
    pN = stdIn.nextLine();
    char a = pN.charAt(1); 
    char b = pN.charAt(2); 
    char c = pN.charAt(3); 
    char d = pN.charAt(5); 
    char e = pN.charAt(6); 
    char f = pN.charAt(7); 
    char g = pN.charAt(9); 
    char h = pN.charAt(10); 
    char i = pN.charAt(11); 
    char j = pN.charAt(12); 



    if (pN.length() == 13 && pN.charAt(0)=='(' && pN.charAt(4)== ')' && pN.charAt(8)=='-')
    {




        if (a>=0 && a<=9)
        {
            if (b>=0 && b<=9)
            {
                if (c>=0 && c<=9)
                {
                    if (d>=0 && d<=9)
                    {
                        if (e>=0 && e<=9)
                        {
                            if (f>=0 && f<=9)
                            {
                                if (g>=0 && g<=9)
                                {
                                    if (h>=0 && h<=9)
                                    {
                                        if (i>=0 && i<=9)
                                        {
                                            if (j>=0 && j<=9)
                                            {

                                                System.out.print("This is a valid phone number!");
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }


    else System.out.println("Not a vaid phone number.");
}

}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use regular expressions in this task (i.e. is this homework)?

Comment: People yell at me if I post an answer telling you "use a debugger," which is, of course, the right thing to do in this situation.

Comment: If it's allowable, you can use Google's libphonenumber (`PhoneNumberUtil.parse()`) to quickly get what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not allowed to use `RegEx` or if it is too difficult to understand, try simplifying your nested if's by a simple `switch` inside a loop, it is much more readable and maintenance is the **easiest** :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String pn = scan.nextLine();
        boolean valid = true;

        if (pn.length() == 13){
            for (int i = 0 ; i < 13 ; i++){
                switch(i){
                case 0 : valid = pn.charAt(0) == '(';break;
                case 4 : valid = pn.charAt(4) == ')';break;
                case 8 : valid = pn.charAt(8) == '-';break;
                default : valid = Character.getNumericValue(pn.charAt(i)) >= 0 &&  Character.getNumericValue(pn.charAt(i))<= 9 ; break;
                }
                if (!valid) break;
            }
            if (!valid) System.out.println("Invalid number");
        }else{
            valid = false;
            System.out.println("Invalid length");
        }

        if (valid){
            System.out.println(pn + " is a valid telephone number");
        }
    }
```

Also, to avoid working with the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) value of a char, try using the `Character.getNumericValue(Char c)` method. It returns a `numeric` that you can use for your tests, like above.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to use pattern-matching (regex) for validation:

```
...
pN = stdIn.nextLine();
System.out.println(pN.matches("\\(\\d{3}\\)\\d{3}-\\d{4}"));
```

Even if you want to have it check if each character is a digit, using so many nested if's is not the way to go. Instead, define a simple method that applies the check, say:

```
private static boolean isDigit(char x) {
    return x>=0 && x<=9;
}
```

and then do:

```
if ( isDigit(a) && isDigit(b) && ...) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use regex in this case:

You can use following :

```
String pattern = "(\\(\\d{3}\\)\\d{3}-\\d{4})";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
pN = stdIn.nextLine();
Matcher m = r.matcher(pN);
  if (m.find( )) {
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
  } else {
     System.out.println("NO MATCH");
  }
```